# How do I assign a vNIC to a distributed port group based on its current port group membership?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I have a VM with 3 network adapters:

vNIC1 : OldPortGroup1
vNIC2 : OldPortGroup2
vNIC3 : OldPortGroup3

I need to change the port group of these adapters to NewPortGroup1, NewPortGroup2, NewPortGroup3. I do not know which vNIC is currently assign to what port group but I do know the old port group names. I need to assign the New port group to the vNIC based on its membership to the old port group. The following code does not work:

```
Get-Datacenter MyDatcenter | Get-VM MyVM | Get-NetworkAdapter | Where-Object { $_.NetworkName -like "OldPortGroup1" } | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName NewPortGroup1
```

This will return all the vNICs for all virtual machines that are on that network. It does not obey the -VM parameter on Get-VM. As far as I am concerned it is impossible to do what I am thinking. I have tried if statements, switch statements, etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't work right if you don't actually manually import the Vds plugin. This can be done using the following command:

```
Get-PSSnapin -Registered -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Vds
```